# Using the same playlist between two devices

Tags: itunes

If I create some playlists on my iPod, is there a way I can import the same playlist on my iPhone? So that if there are the same songs on the iPhone it would play them.

Comment: Do you use iTunes to sync both iOS devices to the same computer? Where do you create the playlists, on the computer running iTunes or on the iPod?

Comment: Yes I use iTunes to sync both iPod and iPhone.. I have created the playlist in the iPod.